# Vertically aligning divs with different heights

Tags: css

I have the following page where the arrows are used to move text between the three columns.

[image]

However I wish to position each arrow so that it is vertically aligned with the sentence that it is associated with. How might I achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/barra/121v4ow8/198/

```
<div class="divsholder">
  <div id="col-1" class="column"></div>
  <div id="right-1" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="left-1" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="col-2" class="column"></div>
  <div id="right-2" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="left-2" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="col-3" class="column"></div>
</div>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%
}

.divsholder {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.divsholder > div {
  flex: 1;
}

div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 5px;
}

#left-1,
#left-2,
#right-1,
#right-2 {
    max-width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Can you change your DOM structure or add scrollBar to text content?

Comment: I'd prefer not to do this. The text content will consist of a single sentence which Id like to be able to read quickly.

Comment: is a js solution allowed ? as i think not faisable with CSS

Comment: @Temani Afif Yes js would do fine.

Comment: @Akansh Gulati The DOM structure can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of JQuery solution. The idea is to add a margin-bottom depending on the height of the text element.

```js
let data = {
    "bad":["bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb", "a", "d"], 
    "unknown": ["m", "i", "ddddddddddddd dddddddd ddddddddd dddddddddd", "d", "l","e"], 
  "good": ["g", "o", "o", "d"]
};
let a = data.bad;
let b = data.unknown;
let c = data.good;
a.sort();
b.sort();
c.sort();

let draw_column = (id, data, func) => {
  data.forEach((n, i) => $('#' + id).append(
    $('<div/>', {
      'text': n,
      'id': id + '-' + i
    }).on({
      'click': () => func(i)
    })
  ))
}

let redraw_column = (id, data, func) => {
  $("#" + id).empty(),
    draw_column(id, data, func)
};

let move_data = (data1, data2, i) => {
    data2.push(
        data1.splice(i, 1)[0]
    ),
    data1.sort(),
    data2.sort()
}

let left_data = (l) => {
    return Array(l).fill('<');
}

let right_data = (l) => {
    return Array(l).fill('>');
}

let move = (data1, data2, i) => {
    move_data(data1,data2,i),
    redraw_column("col-1", a, i => {}),
    redraw_column("right-1",right_data(a.length),i=>move(a, b, i)),
    redraw_column("left-1",left_data(b.length),i=>move(b, a, i)),
    redraw_column("col-2", b, i => {}),
    redraw_column("right-2",right_data(b.length),i=>move(b, c, i)),
    redraw_column("left-2",left_data(c.length),i=>move(c, b, i)),
    redraw_column("col-3", c, i => {})
}

draw_column("col-1", a, i => {});
draw_column("right-1", right_data(a.length), i => move(a, b, i));
draw_column("left-1", left_data(b.length), i => move(b, a, i));
draw_column("col-2", b, i => {});
draw_column("right-2", right_data(b.length), i => move(b, c, i));
draw_column("left-2", left_data(c.length), i => move(c, b, i));
draw_column("col-3", c, i => {});

var count = 0;
$('#right-1 > div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-bottom',($('#col-1 > div').eq(count).outerHeight()-$(this).outerHeight()+4)+'px');
    count++;
})

count = 0;
$('#left-1 > div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-bottom',($('#col-2 > div').eq(count).outerHeight()-$(this).outerHeight()+4)+'px');
    count++;
})
count = 0;
$('#right-2 > div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-bottom',($('#col-2 > div').eq(count).outerHeight()-$(this).outerHeight()+4)+'px');
    count++;
})

count = 0;
$('#left-2 > div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-bottom',($('#col-3 > div').eq(count).outerHeight()-$(this).outerHeight()+4)+'px');
    count++;
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%
}

.divsholder {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.divsholder > div {
  flex: 1;
}

div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 5px;
}

#left-1,
#left-2,
#right-1,
#right-2 {
    max-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divsholder">
  <div id="col-1" class="column"></div>
  <div id="right-1" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="left-1" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="col-2" class="column"></div>
  <div id="right-2" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="left-2" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="col-3" class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works if the container widths stay fixed. You need to handle viewport resize also.

Comment: @t-jam i know, i simply showed the idea using jQuery. This need to be optimized and also considered for responsive.

Answer (score -1):

As the containers are responsive and text flows with dynamic height inside these containers, you can't know where to position the arrow elements beforehand if they're separated, so you have two options:

1. Have the text and each arrow share a container so you can position the arrow relative to the text. This is probably cleanest. You could even use :before and :after pseudo-elements to create the arrows, and show/hide the left or right (:before or :after) arrows depending on which column it is in.
2. Get vertical positions of each text block with JavaScript and apply these heights to the relative arrow elements. With your code, you'll need to update these positions on every click (when elements move columns) and on resize.